# Trying to show show alert function but facing issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

Here I have a parent component with a button and a child component with a function to show an alert.

but I was getting this error,

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.
```

**code:**

```
import { useRef } from "react"

const ChildComp = () => {
  function showAlert() {
    alert("Hello from Child Component")
  }
  return <div></div>
}

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <button>Click Me</button>
      <ChildComp ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we enclose the child component with `forwardRef`, it receives a second parameter apart from `props`, which is the `ref` passed from the `parent component`.

Now with the help of this ref, we can specify which functions can be accessed by the `parent component`. This can be done using `useImperativeHandle hook`, as shown below:

```
import { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react"

const ChildComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showAlert() {
      alert("Hello from Child Component")
    },
  }))
  return <div></div>
})

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => childCompRef.current.showAlert()}>Click Me</button>
      <ChildComp ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I found this helpful as well, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const ChildComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  function showAlert() {
    alert("Hello from Child Component");
  }
  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
});

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <button>Click Me</button>
      <ChildComp ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here you have to use forwardRef in child component if you want to pass refs.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const ChildComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  function showAlert() {
    alert("Hello from Child Component");
  }
  return <button ref={ref} onClick={(e)=>showAlert()}>Click Me</button>;
});

function App() {
  const childCompRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      
      <ChildComp ref={childCompRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```